# How to update a number in HTML by incrementing it when a new text input is submited?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, input

I need to add +1 to the total number of tweets when a new tweet (text input) is submitted:

[image]

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="Twitter">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Twitter Clone</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="profileArea">
      <img id="profile" src="http://potdeli.webs.com/twitter.png" alt="tweet">
      <p style="color:white;"><strong>Tweeto</strong></p>
      <p>@TweetoTwiteech</p>
      <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Tweets</th>
    <th colspan="1">Following</th>
    <th colspan="1">Followers</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
    </div>

    <div class="tweets" ng-app="" ng-controller="TweetsController">

        <form method="POST" action="" ng-submit="addTweet()">
        <h2>Compose new tweet</h2>
        <input  name="tweet" type="text" ng-model="newTweet" ng-maxlength="140"  placeholder="What's happening?">
        <button type="submit" value="addTweets">Tweet!</button>
        </form>
        <div class="tweetDisplay" ng-repeat="tweet in tweets track by $index">{{ tweet }}
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.5/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="tweets.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is the JavaScript:

```
function TweetsController($scope) {
  $scope.tweets = ["First sample tweet", "Second sample tweet"];

  $scope.addTweet = function() {
    if(this.newTweet) {

  $scope.tweets.push($scope.newTweet);
      $scope.newTweet = "";
    }
  };
}
```

I tried a couple of things but I didn't get the desired result, also I checked out a few similar Stack Overflow questions but I wasn't able to get it figured out.

Comment: Can you include one of the things you tried please so we can help you fix the issue?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is move the `<table>` into the HTML part that's controlled by your controller. Then you need to replace the `2` with `{{ tweets.length }}` - - Edit: don't use jQuery, you're supposed to use angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh man, I can't believe what a half-wit I am! I just added:

```
  <td>{{ tweets.length }}</td>
```

Instead of number 2, as the number of tweets and placed this on the body:

```
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="TweetsController">
```

Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 0):

Your table markup is outside of your controller scope. Make it part of your controller scope, and then you could print a counter value there, such as `$scope.tweets.length`

Comment: What `counter value` ? Where is `there`?

Comment: @Jorge In its current form this is a comment (a bad copy of mine), not an answer. (also: this Q is solved by taking Angular 101, so it's going to be closed/deleted soon anyway)

Comment: I've updated my answer. Will format better when not on my iPad.

Comment: @Chris: I disagree, I consider this as an answer, albeit one without code. Secondly, I didn't read your comment before posting my answer. I'm just trying to answer questions and help the community during my lunch break.